# Incorrect values is displayed while using npf.rate()

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe as shown below and I need to calculate interest for each observation and hence I used npf.rate() function from numpy_financial package.

```
annual_interest = dict({"Id" : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
                        "Period" : [24, 23, 18, 12, 36, 34, 60],
                        "EMI" : [0, 0, 0, 87548, 58405, 2969, 22877],
                        "Amount" : [2300, 38400, 31580, 80000, 46500, 68000, 1118691]})
df = pd.DataFrame(annual_interest)

df['int_py'] = df.apply(lambda x : (npf.rate(x['Period'], -x['EMI'], x['Amount'], 0))*12, axis =1)

## Excel code used: =RATE(Period, -EMI, AMOUNT)*12
df['exc'] = [-11.9642098, -11.9724795, -11.99528627, "#NUM!", "#NUM!", 0.293622, 0.083614]
df.head(10)
```

Here column = int_py is the one I created using npf.rate() and column = exc is the one I used RATE() function from Excel. Both of these function works same however giving completely different answer.

For last 2 observation it is working correctly however for 1st-5 observation I am facing this issue.

Is there something that I missed or I am doing wrong?

Comment: First note that from the Excel [`RATE`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/rate-function-9f665657-4a7e-4bb7-a030-83fc59e748ce) docs, "If the successive results of RATE do not converge to within 0.0000001 after 20 iterations, RATE returns the #NUM! error value."

Comment: Okay thanks but what about 1st 3 observation. Python is display blank value however excel is giving Interest rate

Comment: You can reproduce npf's results using the [`rate`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy-financial/blob/master/numpy_financial/_financial.py#L602) code.